# Time limit of an HTTP POST request

Tags: http, post, arduino

When sending an HTTP POST request, is there a time window in which all of the message body must be sent? I am sending many lines of data via an Arduino, and since I need to access an SD card to get the data (Not enough room in SRAM of the Arduino), it takes a while.

There are 100 lines of POST body, and it takes about 1 minute for all of the data to be sent. I keep getting an HTTP response code of 400, bad request and I am not sure if this is why.

Thanks

Comment: Bad request would be something else. There's another response code for that. Most servers have a built-in limit which is usually configurable.

Comment: The browser may have a time limit waiting for a response, but it will depend on the browser.

Comment: That answers my question, thanks Andrew. How do I proceed from here? There is no answer to accept. (Sorry I am new)

Comment: Normally, there's no limit imposed as to the speed of transmission. As long as your data keeps flowing and does not stall for, e.g., 5 minutes in the process there should be no problem. - As Andrew said, HTTP 400 probably indicates some problem with the syntax of your request. Look at the exact, full request which is sent across the network, then try to issue that request interactively, using telnet for example, then try to find the error in the request, fix it and include the fix in your Arduino code.

Comment: Gotcha. I found the source of the problem, it was an incorrect content-length field (too short), which returned a 500 response code due to problems with the server, then a 400 response code for the extra data that was sent after the cutoff imposed by content-length. Thanks